# how to find difference between two dates in terms of day by getting date as user input

Tags: python, date, datetime, difference

I need to find the difference between two dates in terms of days by getting date as a user input. I tried to get date using `raw_input` but I'm getting an error. I'm using 2.7 version of python.

```
import time
from datetime import date
day1 = int(raw_input("enter the date in this format (yyyy:mm:dd)")
day2 = int(raw_input("enter the date in this format (yyyy:mm:dd)")
diff = day2-day1
print diff
```

Comment: read docs for [`datetime.strptime()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to parse those dates into something a little more meaningful. Use the [`datetime.datetime.strptime()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) method:

```
from datetime import datetime

day1 = raw_input("enter the date in this format (yyyy:mm:dd)")
day2 = raw_input("enter the date in this format (yyyy:mm:dd)")
day1 = datetime.strptime(day1, '%Y:%m:%d').date()
day2 = datetime.strptime(day2, '%Y:%m:%d').date()
diff = day2 - day1
print diff.days
```

The `datetime.datetime.date()` method returns just the date portion of the resulting `datetime` object.

Answer (score 2):

If you are expecting the input in the form `"yyyy:mm:dd"`, you cannot simply cast it to `int`.

Besides `strptime`, you can parse the input by yourself.

```
day1 = [int(i) for i in raw_input('...').split(':')]
d1 = datetime.date(*day1) 
day2 = [int(i) for i in raw_input('...').split(':')]
d2 = datetime.date(*day2) 
diff = d2 - d1
print diff.days
```

---

Thanks to @JF Sebastian, even simpler way using `lambda` by defining:

```
str2date = lambda s: datetime.date(*map(int, s.split(':')))
```

Simply call:

```
date = str2date(raw_input('...'))
```

Comment: I think this should be a comment.

Comment: `str2date = lambda s: date(*map(int, s.split(':')))`

Comment: Updated! Cool use with `lambda`!

Answer (score -1):

```
from datetime import date
import datetime

date1= datetime.date.today()
date_1=print(date1.strftime("The date of order: %d/%m/%Y"))

year = int(input('Enter a year: '))
month = int(input('Enter a month: '))
day = int(input('Enter a day: '))

date2 = datetime.date(year, month, day)
date_2= print(date2.strftime("Payment due date: %d/%m/%Y"))
difference=(date2-date1).days

print("The number of days for payment is: ", difference)
```

Its a program that allows a the user to find the difference between today's date and the input date from the user, in **DAYS**